# Get rid of the influence of a predictor

Tags: categorical-data, data-mining, naive-bayes

I am currently working on a data mining project during an in internship, and I use among others methods decision trees.
My problem is that I have a categorical predictor very influent on classification, but I want to ignore this influence to better analyze the behaviour of other predictors.

I could of course delete this predictor from the algorithm but the tree would be biased by this invisible parameter.

I have done a Naive Bayes model of the influence of this predictor but I don't know how to use this to debiased the tree.

Any idea would be appreciated
Thanks in advance,
Pierrick

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. my problem is that this predictor is categorical, not numerical, so I cannot see how to do this linear regression.
And as Y is True or False (1 or zero), ϵ will be contained in [-1 1] am I right ? So I also need to find a treshold in those values in order to perform this classification ? I tried this method by doing a linear model with this predictor transformed by target based coding (didn't try dummy coding because I have a lot of levels), and it appears that the 0-hold residuals (numeric residuals contained in [-1 1] transformed into binary logical variable by tres

Answer (score 1):

You could stratify and do a separate tree for each level of the predictor you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I already tried that but now I haven't a satisying number of observation for a lot of levels. So the trees are really unstables.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to compute a linear model with only your predictor, check that indeed it explains a certain amount of variance in your data, and then work with the residuals from that analysis. That would give you your data minus that specific variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That seems like a great idea, but what linear model of classification (with categorical predictor)should I use ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I did not really understand what you meant. You mean to use the residuals as the target variable or as a new predictor replacing this annoying parameter?

Comment: Sorry replying so late. What I meant is to use the residuals as the new target variable. That way you have eliminated the influence from that parameter you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I would first study the influence of your predictor over your variable $Y$ with a scatterplot or things like that.

Then you could indeed do simple linear regression like this:

$Y=\beta_{1}f(X_{1})+\beta_{0}+\epsilon$ where $f$ is a function of your choice that you may have discovered intuitevely with a scatter plot.

Theoratically, $\epsilon$ would contain the information of $Y$ depending on other predictors. And then you can do your classification on $\epsilon$.

But several assumptions are made here:

- A certain linearity in your model
- The fact that all your predictors are independent

I'm not sure that it will work but you can try it.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. my problem is that this predictor is categorical, not numerical, so I cannot see how to do this linear regression.

Comment: And as Y is True or False (1 or zero), ϵ will be contained in [-1 ; 1] am I right ? So I also need to find a treshold in those values in order to perform this classification ?